# Why my HTML page is empty in a new opened browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

My index.html has a button(`id="my-btn"`):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My INDEX PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><input type="button" id="my-btn" value="OPEN NEW WINDOW"/>
        <script src="js/my.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***js/my.js*** handles button click event, when `my-btn` button is clicked, **a new browser window will be opened** with a new page(***test.html***)

my.js:

```
$('#my-btn').click(function(){  
  window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');
});
```

The new page(**test.html**) opened in new browser window:

**test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-name"></div>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the new page, ***test.js*** will be invoked and it will append the text "JOHN" as the content of this page

**js/test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-name").append("<strong>JOHN</strong>");
});
```

But, when the **test.html** page opened in a new popped up browser window, I did not see the text "JOHN", it is an empty page, why?

(I have jquery-1.5.1.js under "js/" directory, and all JavaScript files are under js/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple here...

You're calling $(document).ready... before $ is defined.

This happens in the jquery, so you need to switch up your script order:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The content of test.js depends on jQuery, but you don't try to load jQuery until after you have executed everything in test.js.

Switch the script elements around.